# Reading Active Directory thumbnailPhoto with Node.js and activedirectory2 and displaing it in svg

Tags: node.js, active-directory

How can I read the property thumbnailPhoto and display it in the page? What type is the stored photo? I would like to display it in svg after it.

I have tried this:

---

```
  var buf = Buffer.from(user['thumbnailPhoto']);
  var b64 = buf.toString('base64');
```

I have 3 photos in my test AD and all begin with the same symbols in base64.

What should be the prefix before the base64 simbols?